# Firebase iOS Swift: how to pick a random userProfile?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, random, arc4random

I am new at Firebase, and I am trying to build an app where its shows an random user profile when users start the app (kind of like Tinder).

After a couple hours testing stuff, I found an solution it works but if feels wrong! I call an observer inside another observer, is this good? two connections? I don't know but it feels bad! but I can't find another solution.

Is my code good or bad? if isn't correct can someone give me some good advice how to do it?

My firebase database structure:

```
"profiles": {
    "1": {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "age": "36",
      "location": "Los Angeles",
      "gender": "male",
    },
    "2": { ... },
    "3": { ... }
  },
```

my Swift IOS Firebase Code

```
var profilesRef: DatabaseReference!
let profilesRef = Database.database().reference().child("profiles")

profilesRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

    let profilesCount = snapshot.childrenCount
    let diceRoll : String = String(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(postsCount)))

    profilesRef.child(diceRoll).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let profileDict = snapshot.value {
            let profile =  Profile(profileData: profileDict as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
            print(profile.age)
        }
    })
})
```

It works but it feels wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to pull from the database a second time. What you can do is take the snapshot that you received from the first one, store the value in a dictionary, and then get the value for the key "diceroll." 
You already pulled the data once, no need to do it again.

Also, a side note, it's not good practice to store profiles under a number, because if someone deletes their profile, or two people create a profile at the same time, there will be discrepancies in the data. I suggest looking into "childByAutoID," and then you can randomize the user selection by storing them in an array and choosing a random index.

Let me know if you have questions!

Comment: thanks for your reply, Nshweky
i don't understand if i don't make my second connection, how do i get my single profile?
Can you help me with the code pls?????

Comment: When you made the first call to the database, the snapshot returned all of the profiles. If you log the snapshot.value you should get "1": {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "age": "36",
      "location": "Los Angeles",
      "gender": "male",
    },
    "2": { ... },
    "3": { ... } etc...

Comment: try logging the snapshot.value (from the first database call) if you don't understand.

Comment: yes, i understand, but i just want to print one profile not all of them and to do this based on the key?

Comment: Something like this: let snap: [AnyHashable: Any] = snapshot.value;
        let age: String = snap[diceroll]["age"]

Comment: hello my friend, when i try your code i get 1 error at the last line "let age" line
`var ref: DatabaseReference!      
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("profiles")
        
        ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            
            let profilesCount = snapshot.childrenCount
            let diceRoll : String = String(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(profilesCount)))
            let snap: [AnyHashable: Any] = snapshot.value
            let age: String = snap[diceRoll]["age"]
            
        })`
my error = type ‘Any?’ has no subscript members